# Restrict Network Changes For VirtualBox Manager

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I have a setup with 10 imacs running lion.  The computers are in a lab in which users login with their own credentials, the network considers this computer trusted, and the user has limited privileges on the computer.  I have virtual box installed and would like the users to be able to create their own VM that they are root on and can develop.  The users should be able to change memory settings and such, but not network settings.  We cant have the VM access the network at all.  How can I disable the networking options for Virtualbox and make sure no users without admin on OSX can enable it.  I need it to be deploy-able with a loadset, so anything specific to a single computer cant work, like basing it off of the MAC address.

We need the usb sharing to still work so they can transfer files to the VM, it would also be nice if a usb network adapter could be pluged in so they can connect to a different wireless network that is not linked with the main network.

Short of building Virtual Box and deleting the Network GUI options I have no idea how to do this.

Any Ideas?

Thanks